# How do I use Instruments Time Profiler with clang compiled from the command line?

Tags: c++, macos, compilation, profiling, instruments

I am currently running OS X Mavericks on this machine, and am compiling a C++ scientific computing application.  I would prefer not to convert it to XCode build if I dont have to.

What I am trying to do is to profile the program to find what sections of code are causing it to run slowly.  It is a fairly simple build- roughly 15 source files, and the only flags I am adding are:  -g -O2 -ftree-vectorize.  For example

```
clang++ MySource.cpp -g -O2 -ftree-vectorize -o MySource.o
```

I run the program and launch instruments and attach a time profiler to my application.  This all works fine.  HOWEVER, the hot spot in the code it is identifying makes zero sense, as it is highlighting a line of code that is only called when the class is constructed, and is a fault in construction which logs an error and throws an exception on the following line.  No error is being logged, and no exception being thrown, so I am confident this line of code is not actually the one being executed.  Am I compiling things properly to be used with instruments?  Are there other flags I need to add?  I have noticed that it doesnt automatically link to my source code in instruments- I have to go manually find the source code file in question.